# How to style input component of TextField using styled function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to style MUI TextField component using styled function

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({ padding: 5 });
```

I also want to style Input and input components inside TextField. Previously I did that by applying style

```
<TextField
    InputProps={{ style: { color: 'red' } }}
    inputProps={{ className: '...' }}
/>;
```

Is it possible to style Input and input using styled function so in the end I only use already styled `StyledTextField` component without passing additional style and classname props to StyledTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example showing ways to target the different elements inside `TextField`.

- The CSS properties that aren't nested in another rule are applied to the `FormControl` element (e.g. `margin` below) which is the outermost element of the `TextField`.
- `"& .MuiInputLabel-root": {...}` can be used to target the label element.
- `""& .MuiInputBase-root": {...}` can be used to target the `Input` element (equivalent to styles passed via `InputProps`).
- `"& .MuiInputBase-input": {...}` can be used to target the `input` element (equivalent to styles passed via `inputProps`).

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  margin: 5,
  "& .MuiInputLabel-root:not(.MuiInputLabel-shrink)": {
    transform: "translate(14px, 8px) scale(1)"
  },
  "& .MuiInputLabel-root": {
    color: "green"
  },
  "& .MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
    color: "purple"
  },
  "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
    color: "red"
  },
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: 8
  }
});

export default function BasicTextField() {
  return (
    <>
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Default" />
      <StyledTextField id="styled" label="Styled" />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit target TextField elements]